# add constraint to view in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

I wanted to add an image but stack overflow doesn't allow me to upload any photo because of the reputation issue.
I leave a link for it.
https://www.evernote.com/l/AbqeZCbSUD1GWbDIiigHjtpkOmncUDZglQI

anyway,

I have an `iOS` project with `Xcode 6`.

I made a view controller and added a table view.

```
view controller
- Top Layout Guide
- Bottom Layout Guide
- View
+- Table View
```

After that,

I added a view and a table view cell

```
view controller
- Top Layout Guide
- Bottom Layout Guide
- View
+- Table View
++- View
++- Table View Cell
```

My problem is that the height of View of Table View is about 30 on Story board.
But while running simulator, Table View Cell is almost at the bottom.

But I cannot add constraint to set the height of View of Table View.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can add a link to the images that you want to show to us.

Comment: thank you, @triplegg I just left a link for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, firstly, you should move the second `view` out of the `Table View`. The right layout should be like:

```
view controller
- Top Layout Guide
- Bottom Layout Guide
- View
+- View
+- Table View
++- Table View Cell
```

Then, you should set some proper constraints between the second `View`(The User Name in your case) and `Table View`. 
If you still not familiar with Auto layout and don't know how to work with constraints, I strongly suggest you to take a look at this brilliant article which will solve most of the puzzles :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Finally, you can adjust the height of your table view cell further by using this method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
It may be work for you.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 30;//or your height of UITableViewCell height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get a better of idea of what is wrong in Xcode by using view debugging while the app is running from the Debug menu. But if you have correctly identified the problem you could try to tackle this two ways. You could constrain the size of the table view(bad). Or you could constrain the table view to have no gaps between it and the container view(better).

As far as actual mechanics of adding constraints you can use the constraint buttons in the bottom right of InterfaceBuilder after you select the view you want to constrain. I recommend using the left hand sidebar in list mode to accurately select the view you want instead of trying to click on it in IB.